# Print strings on Apex3 using printer command language

Tags: android, thermal-printer

How to print strings on Apex3 using printer command language or SDK?

I created a library for android application to print Bitmap images on mobile thermal printers:
Apex3, 3nStar, PR3, Bixolon, Sewoo LK P30 using appropriate SDKs.
It works fine but pretty slow, every ticket of 30 cm length takes 20-40 secs to print (it depends on type of printer). 
For 3nStar and Apex3 I started to do improvements to speed up a printing.

For 3nStar I developed a class which prints a header logo and formatted text with spanish characters. 
(different alignments and different fonts for different parts of a ticket)
so, the ticket looks very similar as Bitmap image but a printing time is only 6 secs.
Now I have to do the same but with Apex3. And here I got stuck.

How I do it on 3nStar for strings:

I send in outputStream bytes which are commands for printer what to do.

`outputStream.write(some_bytes)`

First command always is

`{0x1b, 0x74, 40}  //Esc t ( -- [ISO8859-15 (Latin9)]`

to print spanish characters.

Then, in a loop, for n strings:

I choose a font

`{0x1B, 0x21, 0x00}//Esc ! 0 -- 0 is normal, 8 is bold etc.`

where changing last byte I print different fonts: normal, bold, two height, two width and combined fonts.

Next I choose an alignment

`{0x1b, 0x61, 48}  //Esc a 48 for left, 49 for center, 50 for right`

Then I convert a string in bytes using ISO_8859_1 to print spanish characters and also write in outputStream.

`outputStream.write(messageString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))`

And last byte to send is

`{0x0a}            // Move on next line`

And the above approach doesn't work with Apex3, also I failed using 
http://www.old.adtech.pl/upload/Extech_Printer_Command_Language%20Rev_H_05062009.pdf
even though on page 1 of that book is written that is fit for Apex3.
I think I miss something, I start to see how to do it using some SDK feature of Android_SDK_ESC_V1.01.17.01PRO.jar
but I would prefer to do that using direct writing of bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers I found from this 
[manual](http://www.old.adtech.pl/upload/Extech_Printer_Command_Language%20Rev_H_05062009.pdf)

Shortly differences with the approach that I described for 3nStar are:

1)Before printing set a char set

```
ESC F 1 //Esc t - for 3nStar
```

2)Set a font for text, for example

```
ESC K 1 3 CR //ESC F 1 - for 3nStar
```

3)Send a line of text with alignment

For 3nStar I can use an alignment command before sending a text, like

```
ESC 1 49 //Centering
```

But for Apex3 I have to know a line length which depends on type of font, also a length of printing string,
then I get

```
freeSpace = (lineLength - printingString)
```

and set spaces at the begining of a line (right alignment),
 at the end (left alignment) or devide them (centering).

So, for both types of printers I use the same logic which differs only in 3 places.
 It is simplified explanation as a real code includes several classes with hundreds lines of code.